# Is it possible in Pandas to drop just empty cells?

Tags: python, pandas

is it possible to drop empty cells (i mean just the cells, not the row or column).
I've got a dataframe where i just need all numbers to the left side, similar to this one:

Frame with empty cells

[image: Frame with empty cells]

Frame how it should look like

[image: Frame how it should look like]

Comment: No images, please. Can you post `df.to_dict()` or `df.to_clipboard()` to the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move non-empty cells to the left in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062157/move-non-empty-cells-to-the-left-in-pandas-dataframe)