# Use pandas to make sense of malfomed Excel data

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

My job has me doing some data analysis and the exported spreadsheet that is given to me (the ONLY way able to be given) has data that looks like this:

[image]

But what I need it to look like, ideally, would be something like this:
[image]

I've tried some other codes and to be honest I've made a mangled mess and got rid of it as I only succeeded in jumbling the data. I've done several other pandas projects where I was able to sort and make sense of the data, but it had the same structure and was easier to do. At this point I just dont feel I have the logical part of how to go about fixing the data. I would do it manually but it's over 48k lines. Any help you may be able to provide would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is what the data looks like if we *delete blanks and shift-up*:

[image]

Comment: Is the data in excel? or you require specifically pandas to solve the problem?

Comment: [Excel solution](https://www.auditexcel.co.za/blog/shift-cells-up-if-blank-in-excel/#:~:text=Move%20cells%20up%20to%20remove%20blank%20cells,-As%20shown%20below&text=Highlight%20the%20cells%20with%20the,the%20blanks%20and%20click%20OK)

Comment: [Pandas solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32062157/14627505) - only change axis from 1 to 0 (because you are moving not to the left, but up)

Comment: So the data is in .xlsx format (Excel). Your solutions posted are not quite the intended output. The end result is more complex than shifting cells up/left. If I shift the cells up or delete blanks, what I wind up with is something that mangles the data a bit. I'll update the post with an image of what happens if we shift up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('your_excel_file.xlsx')

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[-4:]):
    if col == 'Subscription Name':
        df[col] = df[col].shift(-1)
    elif col == 'Resource Group':
        df[col] = df[col].shift(-2)
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].shift(-3)

out = df.ffill().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

###### `>>> display(out)`

[image]

##### Edit :

You can also use :

```
out = df[df['Resource Name'].notna()].ffill()
```

Or for better efficiency (as per @[Vladimir Fokow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14627505/vladimir-fokow)) :

```
out = df.dropna(how='all').ffill()
```

Instead of :

```
out = df.ffill().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: OMG, Can you explain how this logic works? Like, the end result works perfectly (from what I can tell) but I don't understand the different values for shifting.

Comment: Hi Ryan, you're welcome. We're using here `pandas.DataFrame.shift` that has an argument called `periods` who accepts positive (to shift down) and negative (to shift up) values in a dataframe. So, `df[col].shift(-1)` will shift every value of the column `col` one position/row up, `df[col].shift(-2)` two positions/rows up and so on. You can read more here : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: Ah, okay that's what I was actually manually doing in Excel. Didn't know Pandas had that option. Could you explain why the else statement has a -3 ?

Comment: In `df.columns[-4:]`, we select the four last columns (which need to be shifted) of the excel-file/dataframe. In the `else` statement we take the remained columns (which are 'Ressource Type' and 'Ressource Name', respectively) and we shift their values three positions/rows up.

Comment: **For better efficiency (and to avoid dropping possible duplicates that are actual data):** instead of filling and then dropping duplicates, you can first drop all the rows that contain only `na` values with `df.dropna(how='all')`, and then fill

Comment: The big assumption with this answer is that `'Subscription Name'` is always 1 row below the row it corresponds to, and similarly for other 3 columns that we are shifting. If it is so - it would work correctly. But for example if some `'Subscription Name'` is 2 rows below instead of 1, then the previous name will be for this first row, which would be incorrect (as I understand).

Comment: Nevermind, the exported spreadsheet seems to have the same pattern for all the ID's. Thanks for pointing that out, thought !

Comment: Thanks both of you. This is fantastic and has literally saved me hours of work! One day I'll get to the point where this solution just sort of comes naturally! :D